# Find the 3 node voltages in the figure

Tags: homework, nodal-analysis

[image: schematic]

Can you help me? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: As a general rule, we don't solve homework exercises, but if you show us what you've tried so far, where you got stuck and/or what you would do to try and solve your problem we will be happy to point out any mistake or help you get to the right answer.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please use the [edit] link below the question to add more details to your question. Please [edit] in the KCL equations you have already written down.

Answer (score 2):

You should get into the practice of re-drawing schematics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpeywX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This way at least the components are labeled. But also notice that there is no need to indicate where \$I_1\$ sources because the voltage drop across it is already determined by the voltage at \$V_1\$. The above schematic is slightly simpler to read.

Obviously, \$I_x=\frac{V_2}{R_4}\$. And at this point you should be able to use KCL to set up three equations in three unknowns and solve.